# How to get all but last item in a MEL array?

Tags: arrays, string, selection, maya, mel

I want to get the user selection and assign all but the last object to one array variable and the last selected object to another variable.

how can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I had a working code but it wasn't that nice. so I am changing the first lines which are like this now string $sel[] = `ls -sl`; 
int    $lastSel = size ($sel);
stringArrayRemoveAtIndex(($lastSel - 1), $sel);
string $targetSel[] = $sel;
string $base = $lastSel;
string $baseCopy[] = `duplicate $base`;

Comment: @Andy  `string $wholeSel[] = `ls -sl`;
    string $targetList[] = `ls -sl -hd (size($iniSel1) - 1)`; 
    string $base = $wholeSel[size($wholeSel) - 1];`  I redid it like this and it works. But maybe there is a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$first = `ls -sl -head 1`;
$last = `ls -sl -tail 1`;
string $all_except_last[] = stringArrayRemove(`ls -sl -tail 1`, `ls -sl -fl`);
string $all_except_first[] = stringArrayRemove(`ls -sl -head 1`, `ls -sl -fl`);
//don't forget to use -fl (flat list) flag
```

Comment: thank you. what does the 'flat list' flag do? I didn't find it in the reference. also can we use $list[0] for the first item here?

Comment: Of course you can use $list[0]. Flat list more for components (pSphere1.f[255:258] vs pSphere1.f[255] pSphere1.f[256] pSphere1.f[257] pSphere1.f[258]). Flattens the returned list of objects so that each component is identified individually.